# Specify server request timeout in Spring Boot & Spring WebFlux (Netty)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

We are using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) in 2.4.2 with [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html).

I want the Spring Boot application to terminate all requests to the application that take longer than say 3 seconds to process.

There is [`server.netty.connection-timeout`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server.netty.connection-timeout), but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is there a way to specify such a server request timeout?

Comment: I guess connection-timeout does not refer to the duration that a request is allowed to take for processing, but it refers to the time it takes for establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue i.e. even after configuring  `server.netty.connection-timeout` request would get canceled. So, after some debugging found that timeout was getting set to '30000' by AsyncContext.

So, I configured the following property `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` which change the timeout being set in AsyncContext and the request stopped getting canceled.

Comment: this makes no sense. The question is about how to cancel the request and not about how to stop it from being canceled. Also the `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` is for the mvc stack and not for the webflux stack.

Comment: this is what shows up in google so that is useful still

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR:

Netty has no request timeout*. Add this `WebFilter` to set a request-timeout of 3 seconds using the reactor timeout on every request (here in kotlin, but in Java it works accordingly):

```
@Component
class RequestTimeoutWebFilter : WebFilter {
  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return chain
      .filter(exchange)
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
  }
}
```

* at least I could not find any information in the netty docs.

## Detailed answer

The `connection-timeout` does not refer to the duration that a request is allowed to take for processing, but it refers to the time it takes for establishing the connection.

First, I could not find any spring configuration option that allows setting the request timeout for netty. Then I went through the [netty documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#http-server) to find out that there is no concept of request timeouts on the http server (only on the http client).

Wondering about why such important feature would not be supported, I remembered that we often cannot apply the same concepts as in blocking servers for good reasons. Next, I remembered, that in the reactive world we do not directly implement the handling of the request, but how the handling is assembled - i.e. we hold a `Mono<Void>` that will handle the request. Hence, we can just look at reactor and how to timeout a `Mono`, which is very easy:

```
Mono.create(...)
  .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
```

Next, we just need to figure out, how to apply this to all requests. This is easy as well, because we can just use a `WebFilter` to intercept all requests to apply our timeout (here in kotlin, but in Java it works accoringly):

```
@Component
class RequestTimeoutWebFilter : WebFilter {
  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return chain
      .filter(exchange)
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
  }
}
```

This effectively cancels a request within the set timeout with the following error:

```
2022-10-21 00:08:00.981 ERROR 6289 --- [     parallel-4] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [59dfa990-7]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/some/route"

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 3000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
```

### More tips and hints

- To make the timeout configurable, we can use a custom config variable instead of the hard-coded duration.
- To custimize the `500` status code we can either change the exception by providing a fallback to the timeout as 2nd argument and handle that exception in a controller advice - or we can just use reactors `onErrorReturn`.
- The documentation for [WebFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html) actually states that they should be used to implement timeouts:

  > Contract for interception-style, chained processing of Web requests that may be used to implement cross-cutting, application-agnostic requirements such as security, timeouts, and others.

*Still I think it is expected that spring provides such implementation out-of-the box that can be easily configured.* Maybe we oversaw that it is there, but then I would argue it is too hard to find. ^^

### Alternative solution path

As an alternative, we could use **circuit breakers**. However, those are implemented on the readers side and conceptually are used to protect the reading side against failure of the downstream - rather than protecting the internal processing within the downstream from running too long. They can only be applied to mimic a request timeout when applying them in a dedicated server (e.g. a [spring cloud gateway server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway)) that sits between the actual client and the actual service. When using [Resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs) as implementation, you can use [`TimeLimiter`](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/timeout) to achieve it.